# NaN causing sklearn model to not run

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataset that I am trying to run a logistic regression on using sklearn, but the dataset has NaNs which cause problems. Most of the questions I see online deal with imputing the missing values. However, I don't feel comfortable imputing the missing values. Is there a way to drop all the NaN values in the dataframe or to include only the rows where there is no NaN in all the columns?

I ended up creating a new dataframe keep only the rows that have answers in all columns.

```
df2 = df1[(df1['var1']>=0) & (df1['var2']>=0) & (df1['var3']>=0)]
```

But what if I have 100 columns. What's the best and simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropping rows where at least one entry is NaN:

```
df2 = df1.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
```

Note that the above parameter values are the defaults but I included them anyway just to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Using `all` with `axis =1`

```
df1 = df1.loc[df1.gt(0).all(1),:]
```